# How do I send message to web socket with Tornado

Tags: python, django, websocket, tornado

Hello I am using `Tornado`, `Django` frammwork on backend to handle sockets messages on frontend. I am not too much familar with my project but there is a file in my project where are classes that implement `websocket.WebSocketHandler` and `web.Application`. This is part of this file

```
class Application(web.Application):
    """
    Main Class for this application holding everything together.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        PROJECT_NAME = os.path.basename(os.getcwd())
        os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = PROJECT_NAME + 'tutorial/settings'

        # Handlers defining the url routing.
        handlers = [
            ('/room', SocketHandler),
            ('/room/([a-zA-Z0-9|=%]*)$', SocketHandler),
            ('/video_call', VideoCallSocketHandler),
            ('/video_call/([a-zA-Z0-9|=%]*)$', VideoCallSocketHandler),
        ]
```

In the frontend part is a function:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://domain.com:9003/video_call/' + conferenceId);

ws.onmessage = function (ev) {
    window.location.replace(redirectUrl);
};
```

I belive that this function get's message from our mobile aplication.

So the problem is that I would like to send message to this url or whatever it is `'wss://domain.com:9003/video_call/' + conferenceId` from my python view.

for example:

```
def some_view_function(request, **kwargs):
    conference_id = request.GET.data['conferenceId']
    ...
    if something:
       send message to wss://domain.com:9003/video_call/' + conference_id
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

What about the wrap django code by tornado?

```
def main():
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'docs.settings'
    application = get_wsgi_application()
    container = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(application)

    tornado_app = tornado.web.Application(
       [('.*', tornado.web.FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=container))],        
    )

    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(tornado_app)
    server.bind(8888)
    server.start(0)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Communicate between django and tornado i propose to make communication through the queue, like Redis.

```
def some_view_function(request, **kwargs):
    conference_id = request.GET.data['conferenceId']
    ...
    if something:
       send_to_queue()
```

On tornado side queue listener.

Comment: How about defining `conference_id` in `send_to_queue`. How is the function going to know to which `WebSocket` send the message?